# Cannot read file using Scanner, never gets into loop

Tags: java, file, text

I am trying to read a text file in order to copy some parts of it into a new text file.

This is how I create my Scanner item :

```
// folder
File vMainFolder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),"LightDic");
if (!vMainFolder.exists() & !vMainFolder.mkdirs()) {
  System.out.println("Missing LightDic folder.");
  return;
}

// file
System.out.println("Enter the source file's name : ");
Scanner vSc = new Scanner(System.in);
String vNomSource = vSc.next();

Scanner vSource;
try {
  vSource = new Scanner(new File(vMainFolder, vNomSource+".txt"));
} catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException pExp) {
  System.out.println("Dictionnary not found.");
  return;
}
```

And this is how I wrote my while structure :

```
while (vSource.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.println("test : entering the loop");
  String vMot = vSource.nextLine(); /* edit : I added this statement, which I've forgotten in my previous post */
}
```

When executing the program, it never prints "test : entering the loop".

Of course, this file I am testing is not empty, it is a list of words like so :

```
a
à
abaissa
abaissable
abaissables
abaissai
```

I don't understand what I did wrong, I've used this method a few times in the past.

Comment: What is the filename? and is it inside `~/LightDic/` directory?

Comment: Do you see something it your output?

Comment: What does `System.out.println(new File(vMainFolder, vNomSource+".txt").getAbsolutePath());` print for you?

Comment: **Unrelated**, but are you using something similar to the [*Hungarian Notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in your Java code? I was wondering what's that *v* in the beginning of your variables mean, and I guess it stands for "variable". Anyways, using this notation in Java is not common, it only makes readability worse IMHO...

Comment: "while (vSource.hasNextLine()){...}" will generate an infinite loop as written.  You'll need to actually consume some text each time through the loop to advance the scanner's pointer.  I assume you've verified you're entering the while loop, right?  So the question is, why does vSource.hasNextLine() either block or return false?  The most obvious possibility is that vMainFolder isn't pointed where you think it is.  I suggest you System.out.println(new File(vMainFolder, vNomSource+".txt").getAbsolutePath()); just before you enter the while loop, as jlordo suggested.

Comment: If the above does not solve your problem, could it be the case that your test file has a strange line separator, not recognised as such by the `Scanner`?

Comment: @vidit My file name is FRdic.txt, it is indeed inside LightDic directory.

Comment: @jlordo This is what I obtain printing 
    System.out.println(new File(vMainFolder, vNomSource+".txt").getAbsolutePath()); 

    C:\Users\LeoD\LightDic\FRdic.txt 

it is the correct directory and file

Comment: @informatik01 I am using the French Notation I've learned in school : "a" in front of the fields variable names, "p" in front of the parameter variables and "v" in front of the local variables.
I think it is useful to know well what is the variable I am using.

Comment: @JerryAndrews This is my first statement once into the "while" : String vMot = vSource.next(); so it won't generate an infinite loop. I apologize I didn't copy what I put inside my "while".
Using jlordo method, I found out the file I am using for the Scanner is the right file.

Comment: @Arend The words in my file are separated by a new line "\n". I tried to use vSource.hasNextLine() and vSource.hasNext(). I also tried to add a space at the end of the first words of my file. Finally, I tried to use vSource.useDelimiter("\n"); but it didn't work.

Comment: @SeevenByakko Well, at least in Java (C# etc) it's not common. But it's your personal choice

Comment: Using your code and your test file, I get the infinite loop predicted by @Jerry, so I give up

Comment: @informatik01 I understand it's not common, but I think "vSource" and "source" are both acceptable for reading. The "a", "v", "p" letters only add some information while the rest of the variable name is the same as if I didn't put those letters.

Comment: When I load up this code with that sample file I see `test : entering the loop` six times with no infinite loop.

Comment: Also, on line 3, are you sure you meant to use the `bitwise &` versus the `boolean &&` ?

Comment: @JustinJasmann I meant to use the `boolean &&`, thanks for finding this mistake out. I changed it in my program but I still can't get the `"test : entering the loop"` output :/
Did you load the exact same code as mine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I don't really know why, but I solved the problem changing the encoding of my `FRdic.txt` file from `ANSI` to `UTF-8`, and then the file was read.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Is it normal that a text file encoded in `ANSI` is not read by the JVM ?

Comment: Java expects Unicode by default. If your `ANSI` file does not stick to the fragment common to both character encodings, then reading it as Unicode may cause the JVM to take your newline to be the second byte of another character. `java.io.InputStreamReader` has ways to explicitly set the character encoding.